# Как продлить страницу?

Tags: bootstrap

Приветствую. Пишу сайт через bootstrap. Проблема вот в чем.
Страница с главной - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видно, графа под контент достаточно узкая в высоту. Во вкладке -СТАТЬИ , я также использовал эту же часть ( col-md-8 content ), но там не хватает этой высоты, вы можете увидить на скрине ниже, что текст не влезает сюда. Я решил добавить еще один ряд col-md-2+col-md-8+col-md-2, но текст-то всё равно остаётся на верхнем content...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Еще раз напомню, что структура сайта слева(md-2) середина(md-8) справа(md-2).

Comment: Желательно какое-то решение, как можно блок с контентом увеличить в высоту.... (И блоки по бокам соответственно, чтобы была гармония) ... Надеюсь поможете)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, все обернуто в блок row